# true\false questions on number of solutions in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inequality

I was preparing for the exam, and then I saw a few questions I did not understand regarding number of solutions in combinatorics. I would be glad if you could take a look and correct me if I'm wrong:

(questions are true\false):

1) The number of natural solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=14$ is equal to the number of positive whole number (integer) solutions of: $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10$

2) The number of the positive even natural number solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=14$ is equal to the number of the positive odd natural number solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=14$

3) The number of integer solutions that are either $1$ or $-1$ to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 \geq 0$ is 10.

4) If $|a|=3^3$ and $|b|=3$, then the number of functions from $a$ to $b$ is equal to the number of functions from $b$ to $a$.

What I did:

1)  False.  The number of the natural solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=14$ is $\binom {14+4-1}{3}$ and the number number of positive integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10$ is $\binom {10+4-1}{3}$. It's false because the results are not the same.

2)  False. The number of positive odd natural solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=14$ can be obtained if we divided the result by $2$ ($y_i=x_i/2$), i.e: $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=7$, so $\binom {7+4-1}{3}$. and for the even, we need that $x_i \geq 1$, so $y_i=\frac{x_i-1}{2}$, so $\binom {5+4-1}{3}$.

3)  I don't know how to solve it, but I'll try.  If we said the solution is only $1$, then there were no limits, and the result would be: $4!=24$. However, since it's more larger than $0$, we must have more $1$s than $-1$s, so we have to subtract the cases were we have more $-1$ than $1$, i.e: if at least $3$ variables are $-1$, so we subtract $2$ possibilities (either $3$ are $-1$ or $4$ are $-1$), and we get that the number of solutions is $24-2=22$ (If it was $3!-2$, it would make sense. I think I did it wrong).

4) False. If $|a|=3^3=27$ and $|b|=3$, then the number of functions from $a$ to $b$ is not the same as the number of functions from $b$ to $a$.

Please help me and correct me if I made any mistakes. Did my best to elaborate and explain what I've done. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by natural numbers (is $0$ natural?) and by whole numbers (since in $\# 3$ you appear to say that $-1$ is a whole number).

Comment: It is sometimes hard to follow your reasoning.  for $\#2 $, for example, you are trying to count the "non-even" solutions, by which I assume you mean the solutions with four odd entries) but then you divide each term by $2$ which makes no sense unless they are even.

Comment: For $\#4$, your argument appears to be "this is false because it is false".  Not good enough.

Comment: thank you for your comments. regarding 2: i did so because if i just divided by 2, i would get the uneven(for even i have to make sure it's larger than 1), so this is why i choose it to be as such.
regarding 3: 1 is a whole number(integer as far as i know). is my calculation there was wrong?
regarding 4: it seems obvious. was my decision wrong there?

thank you again for your comments

Comment: Please clarify whether $0$ is considered a natural number.

Comment: I don't understand your work on $2$ at all.  As I say, you appear to be dividing odd integers by $2$ and then using formulas for counting integer solutions.  For $3$, of course $1$ is a whole number but $-1$ is not. Again, I can't really follow your calculation.  What answer do you get?  for $4$, if it is obvious then it should have an easy proof (which it does).

Comment: For $\#3$:  you need at least as many $+1's$ as $-1's$. With four $+1's$ there is exactly one solution.  With three $+1's$ there are four solutions.  With two $+1's$ there are $\binom 42 = 6$ solutions.  Thus, all in, there are $1+4+6=11$ solutions.

Comment: 0 Is a natural number

Comment: In future, please consider posting your questions separately.  Answering multiple questions in one post requires a considerable amount of work.  Also, some users may be able to answer some, but not all, of your questions.  You could at least get answers to those questions while you wait for your other questions to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

1) FALSE
$$
\eqalign{
  & \quad \quad \left( {x_{\,1}  + 1} \right) + \left( {x_{\,2}  + 1} \right) + \left( {x_{\,3}  + 1} \right) + \left( {x_{\,4}  + 1} \right)\quad \left| {\;0 \le x_{\,k}  \in Z} \right.\quad  \Leftrightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Leftrightarrow \quad x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  + x_{\,3}  + x_{\,4} \quad \left| {\;1 \le x_{\,k}  \in Z} \right. \cr} 
$$
It would be **true the reverse** (exchanging 10 and 14).

2) FALSE
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\rm N}{\rm .}\,{\rm sol}{\rm .}\,{\rm of}\;\left\{ {2x_{\,1}  + 2x_{\,2}  + 2x_{\,3}  + 2x_{\,4}  = 14\quad  \Rightarrow \quad x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  + x_{\,3}  + x_{\,4}  = 7\quad \left| {\;1 \le x_{\,k}  \in Z} \right.} \right\} <   \cr 
  &  < {\rm N}{\rm .}\,{\rm sol}{\rm .}\,{\rm of}\;\left\{ {2x_{\,1}  - 1 + 2x_{\,2}  - 1 + 2x_{\,3}  - 1 + 2x_{\,4}  - 1 = 14\quad  \Rightarrow \quad x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  + x_{\,3}  + x_{\,4}  = 9\quad \left| {\;\;1 \le x_{\,k}  \in Z} \right.} \right\} \cr} 
$$

3) FALSE

The number of $-1$'s can be $0$ or $1$ or $2$, corresponding to ${ 4 \choose 0}+{ 4 \choose 1}+{ 4 \choose 2}=11$ ways to place them.

4)  FALSE

Understanding $|a|$ as the number of elements of the set $a$, then the functions $f:a \to b$ are $|b|^{|a|}$ and those $f:b \to a$ are $|a|^{|b|}$

Thanks to *N.F. Taussig* for pointing out the correct interpretation of  question (4), and other misunderstandings.

Comment: Your answer to the first question is incorrect.  Notice that at most three of the summands can be equal to zero.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: sorry, you are right, I confused $\mathbb N$ with $\mathbb Z$

Comment: so 1 is right or wrong?   i see the post was edited

Comment: @BeginningMath: it was wrong the motivation (confusing N with Z). I amended now. But it remains false.

Comment: The first question asks you to compare the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 14$ and the number of positive integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 10$.  You seem to be answering a  different question.  Also, while statement 2 is false, your $x_i$s are positive integers for the even number case and nonnegative integers for the odd number case.  The answer to the fourth question is also false.  To answer it, you have to count the number of functions in each direction.  Your answer to the third question is correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig 1) the number of positive int. solution to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 10$ is equal to those of $(y_1+1)+(y_1+1)+(y_1+1)+(y_1+1)=10$ with the $y$ non-negative, am I wrong ?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: for 2) you are right : $2x+1$ would start from 3, shall be $2x-1$, will amend. Thanks for signalling

Comment: Your answer to the first question is correct.  I read your answer too quickly, so I did not notice how you were notating the nonnegative integers and the positive integers.  Sorry.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: please, and again thanks: this matter of natural with 0 or not is causing much confusion.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: for the q. 4) I do not get your point: for *function* I am considering a bijective or surjective *relation*, what is your interpretation?

Comment: A function is determined by how each element in the domain is assigned.  The number of ways a given element in the domain can be assigned is equal to the number of elements in the codomain.  Consequently, the number of functions $f: A \to B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$.  You can check this formula for $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $B = \{1, 2\}$ by listing each of the possible functions.  The functions need not be injective or surjective.  For instance, the constant function $f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = 1$ is a valid function $f: A \to B$ in the example I gave.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: ok, you put in a different method, however (as I understood it) here we are given $A=\{-27, 27\}$ and $B=\{-3,3\}$ so $|B|^{|A|}=|A|^{|B|}$, which is what I meant to say in another way.

Comment: Now, I understand the source of your confusion.  If $A$ is a set, then $|A|$ denotes the number of elements in $A$.  Hence, there are $27$ elements in set $a$ and $3$ in set $b$.  I didn't really answer your question about the definition of a function.  A *function* $f: A \to B$ is a rule that assigns to each element in set $A$ exactly one element in set $B$.  Lastly, your answers to the first three questions are now correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: ah, that is : because of the small letter I took $|a|=3^3$ as indicating absolute value, and thus the set to be $A={-27,27}$ !